# Get leading element for the lexicographical order

Tags: r, sorting, lexicographic

If `M` is a numeric matrix, I can order its rows with respect to the lexicographical order by running `lexsort(M)` where

```r
lexorder <- function(M) {
  do.call(order, lapply(seq_len(ncol(M)), function(i) M[, i]))
}
lexsort <- function(M) {
  M[lexorder(M), ]
}
```

But I'm only interested in getting the greater row (the last one of the ordered matrix). Can we avoid ordering everything to more efficiently extract the last row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You couls write a recursive function that works faster:

```
lex_max <- function(M,i=1){
  d <- dim(M)
  if(d[1] == 1 | i > d[2])M[1,]
  else lex_max(M[max(M[,i]) == M[,i],,drop = FALSE], i+1)
}

a <- matrix(sample(500, 1e5, TRUE), 10)
```

The timings:

Large number of columns:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(lex_max(a), 
        OP=lexsort(a)[nrow(a),],lexmaxrow(a), check = 'equal')

Unit: microseconds
         expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq     max neval
   lex_max(a)    45.7    57.95    80.442    65.55    87.45   306.4   100
           OP 15819.5 19437.25 25579.100 22246.55 29002.80 68948.8   100
 lexmaxrow(a) 16393.9 18739.65 25210.846 22022.40 29098.75 47731.1   100
```

---

```
a <- matrix(sample(500, 1e5, TRUE), 500)

Unit: microseconds
         expr   min     lq    mean median      uq     max neval
   lex_max(a)   5.7   9.90  93.152  12.85   19.70  7124.0   100
           OP 577.0 629.75 907.524 699.20 1017.70  7771.4   100
 lexmaxrow(a) 470.5 521.05 875.526 619.45  908.85 10049.1   100
```

---

Large number of rows

```
a <- matrix(sample(500, 1e5, TRUE), ncol=10)

Unit: microseconds
         expr   min    lq     mean median      uq     max neval
   lex_max(a)  60.2  97.5  137.462  120.0  164.40   650.5   100
           OP 594.0 775.9 1359.959  966.8 1251.35 14719.9   100
 lexmaxrow(a) 475.1 624.1 1013.927  769.5  936.60 11775.1   100
```

In all the instances the `lex_max` function performs >~10x faster

#### Edit:

If you need the position, you could simply do:

```
which_lexmax <- function(M,i=1, b = seq_len(nrow(M))){
  d <- dim(M)
  if(d[1] == 1 | i > d[2])b[1]
  else lex_max(M[mx <- max(M[,i]) == M[,i],,drop = FALSE], i+1, b[mx])
}
 which_lexmax(a)
```

Comment: nice recursion approach, +1! one more thing, recursion is less efficient than simply using loops, so you should improve the performance if you use `for`, `while` or `repeat`.

Comment: Thanks. In fact I need *the index* of the leading row, I've just realized.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent first I noticed an error in the code. It should be `i > d2` and not `i >= d2`

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent editted accordingly. look at the edit

Answer (score 2):

## Update

If you want both the row with highest lexicographical order ***and*** the row index, you can try the code below

```
lex_max2 <- function(M) {
    i <- 1
    nc <- ncol(M)
    idx <- 1:nrow(M)
    repeat {
        p <- max(M[, i]) == M[, i]
        idx <- idx[p]
        M <- M[p, ]
        if (length(idx) == 1) {
            return(list(lexmaxval = M, index = idx))
        } else {
            i <- i + 1
        }
    }
}
```

and an example is

```
> M <- rbind(c(1, 2, 3), c(1, 2, 2), c(2, 3, 2), c(2, 2, 3))

> lex_max2(M)
$lexmaxval
[1] 2 3 2

$index
[1] 3
```

---

## Previous Solution

Similar idea to [Onyambu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76676046/12158757) but using `repeat` rather than recursion

```
lex_max2 <- function(M) {
    i <- 1
    nc <- ncol(M)
    repeat {
        M <- M[max(M[, i]) == M[, i], ]
        if (length(M) == nc) {
            return(M)
        } else {
            i <- i + 1
        }
    }
}
```

and you can see a bit speed improvement

```
> set.seed(0)

> M1 <- matrix(sample(500, 1e6, TRUE), ncol = 100)

> microbenchmark(
+     lex_max(M1),
+     lex_max2(M1),
+     check = "equal"
+ )
Unit: microseconds
         expr  min    lq    mean median     uq    max neval
  lex_max(M1) 67.3 88.10 154.193  90.45 101.30 5700.1   100
 lex_max2(M1) 60.0 85.75  94.461  87.80  97.15  158.9   100

> M2 <- matrix(sample(500, 1e7, TRUE), 500)

> microbenchmark(
+     lex_max(M2),
+     lex_max2(M2),
+     check = "equal"
+ )
Unit: microseconds
         expr   min     lq    mean median     uq   max neval
  lex_max(M2) 135.9 187.00 232.651 200.25 254.95 597.1   100
 lex_max2(M2)  89.6 113.15 152.559 126.20 159.40 528.7   100
```

Comment: Thanks, but that does not work for `M <- rbind(c(1,2,3), c(1,2,3), c(1,3,3), c(1,3,3))`.

Comment: But my rows are distinct, does that always work in this case ?

Comment: Nope: ` M <- rbind(c(1,2,3), c(1,2,2), c(2,2,2), c(2,2,3))`.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent shouldn't it be `c(2,2,3)` as the output? Or, what should it be?

Comment: yes, but it generates an error. Also with my true code.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent weird, what error is it? I don't have any error with `M` in the comment, and it gives the the desired `c(2,2,3)`.

Comment: Ah maybe I did something wrong. But my code crashes, and it's hard to identify which matrix causes the crash. Unless I print it in the function...

Comment: Or maybe this was my modification... In fact I need *the index* of the row, not the row.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent See my update, you will have both the row and the row index in the output. Also, you are free to modify the code to keep the index only, it's definitely  up to your need.